# Does Tilapia have a greater inflammatory potential than bacon?

Tags: nutrition

From: http://www.eatthis.com/tilapia-is-worse-than-bacon

> While most health experts agree we should be eating more fish (for all the reasons listed above), **this Eat This, Not That! research has found the inflammatory potential of farmed tilapia to be greater than a burger, doughnuts  - even pork bacon!**

Is there research supporting or refuting this specific claim about the [inflammatory potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflammation#Diet_and_inflammation) of tilapia vs. bacon?

Answer (score 3):

According to [The Content of Favorable and Unfavorable Polyunsaturated Fatty Acids Found in Commonly Eaten Fish](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002822308005154?via%3Dihub) *Journal of the American Dietetic Association*, Volume 108, Issue 7, July 2008, Pages 1178-1185:

> For individuals who are eating fish as a method to control inflammatory diseases such as heart disease, it is clear from these numbers that tilapia is not a good choice. All other nutritional content aside, the inflammatory potential of hamburger and pork bacon is lower than the average serving of farmed tilapia.

Comment: Notably, farmed tilapia may not contain the fatty oils viewed as making fish "healthy," though they will be a source of protein. Salmon, tuna, etc. contain oil because they consume oil-producing algae or smaller fish that eat the algae; tilapia fed on algae or quality food will also contain oil, but tilapia raised on other diets will not.

Comment: @jeffronicus: citation?

Comment: Some of that is just the physiology of marine organisms; the reason we study algae for biofuels is they produce lipids. Here's a chart from government data showing that farm-fed tilapia has less than 200 mg of omega-3 per 3-ounce portion, compared to more than 1,500mg for wild herring: http://www.seafoodhealthfacts.org/seafood-nutrition/healthcare-professionals/omega-3-content-frequently-consumed-seafood-products

Comment: "Cold-water fatty fish have the highest content of omega-3 fatty acids because their physiology, environment and diet promote omega-3 fatty acid production in their flesh." http://www.med.umich.edu/umim/food-pyramid/fish.html